# AutoML Translation Supported languages

Tags: automl, google-translation-api, google-cloud-automl-nl

I have a question about AutoML Translation.
In the list of supported languages, we did not find our language. Can we add the Kazakh language to create our dataset? Example (translation from Russian to Kazakh)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they only support the next [Languages list](https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/languages).

Note that [AutoML Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/) is on Beta stage so it might get changed and the Supported languages list might be changed as well.